# meaning of 從 in 必操几杖以從之

Tags: meaning, classical-chinese, verbs

In the following sentence, what does 從 mean? What is the implicit subject of 從之?

> 謀於長者，必操几杖以從之。

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Simplified Chinese adds a layer of difficulty for interpretation in classical texts, please avoid it and find a faithful transcription if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the verse in the book of rites (禮記), chapter 曲禮上:

> 謀於長者・必操几杖以從之

i would interpret it as:

[in situation of | if | when] seeking advice (謀) from (於) an elder (長者)・[one] must (必) hold (操) [readily] the “arm rest” & staff (a strong stick or pole) (几杖 —> 憑几 & 手杖); for the purpose of (以) attending to (從之)

https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&id=9489

so, “從之” refer back to the “elder” that one’s seeking advice from.

btw, an “arm rest” (憑几) is a tool, when people is sitting on a mat, on floor, for putting their arms on it for resting, something like this:

[image]
[image]

have fun :)

Comment: You mean the elder is the one who does the action of attending? Or the person who is seeking advice?

Comment: the asker prepared the tools for attending to / caring for the elder.